# AJAX post request reports fail while actually succeeds

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, post

Weird situation. I am using AJAX to post some data to a service, and that succeeds - meaning that I can really see the new data stored in the database. However, my code doesn't enter the `done()` part, but always ends up in the `fail()` part for some reason. I am providing the relevant code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // on-click listener
    $("#btn-submit").click(function(e) {
        // obtain data from the form
        var employee = {
            FirstName: $("#input-first-name").val(),
            LastName: $("#input-last-name").val(),
            BirthPlace: $("#input-birth-place").val(),
            CurrentPlace: $("#input-current-place").val(),
            Gender: $("#input-gender").val(),
            Department: $("#input-department").val(),
            OIB: $("#input-oib").val()
        };

        // AJAX call on button clicked
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/",
            data: employee
        }).done(function(){
            alert("Successfully created new entry!");
        }).fail(function(xhr) {
            //alert("Fail!");
            console.log(xhr);
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to log the error message, but it's simply like this:

```
{readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
```

The response from the server is generated as follows.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]EmployeeDto employee)
{
    long id = persistence.SaveEmployee(employee);

    // create http response
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, String.Format("/api/employee/{0}", id));

    return response;
}
```

Which generates following response with 201 Created status code:

```
    Date: Sat, 16 Sep 2017 11:11:51 GMT
Server: Mono.WebServer.XSP/4.4.0.0 MacOSX
Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/employee/40
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 153
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

I don't really know what that means, nor why the code goes in the fail part when it actually manages to post a new entry. Any ideas?

Comment: what data does your server returns? i see that your `.done` callback doesnt expect any data

Comment: The fail callback definition is `jqXHR.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});` Try logging textStatus and errorThrown.

Comment: @Salketer textStatus is empty and errorThrown is just "error".

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is your case as you never mentioned what is the data returned from the server.
According to the [DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), as of jquery 1.9 an empty response is also rejected.

> The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
>   rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty
>   response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null
>   or {} instead.

Comment: I added the service response. It just returns the status code and the added employee id.

Comment: well this not a `json` response, and the docs says: "_any malformed JSON is rejected_". try to return a `json` object to see if this is the case

Comment: I edited the post, so I changed my service to return "application/json" response, but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `function(xhr)` to

```
function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

and your console log

```
console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
```

Thus, you can now monitor if there is an error on your request since we do not now what is going on on your Ajax request.

Comment: Here is the output of that: {readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …} "error" ""

Comment: Like this..  success: function(out) 
{
if(out.msg == 1)
{
 alert('record created');
}
else
{
 alert('Something went wrong');
}
}, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
{
console.log(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown);
alert("An error occured on the request.");
}